# Why is Vishnu holding a Trishula here?

Tags: vishnu

Found this image on the internet without any description
Looks like Keshava but with a Trishul, Shankha, Chakra, Padma

What's this particular form called?
[image]

Comment: may be he is Ananta/Shesha

Comment: It is a Thai depiction of Vishnu, not from the Indian subcontinent.